# Android WorkManager caused native crash

Tags: android, crash, native

in my android project I'm getting an android native crash after I'm starting a Work-Continuation.
I attached the tombstone from android to my Git repo.
This is a summary of the tombstone:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:11/RSR1.200819.001.A1/6823625:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2020-10-20 12:40:20+0000
pid: 18189, tid: 18189, name: mple.workertest  >>> com.example.workertest <<<
uid: 10219
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3d
Cause: null pointer dereference
    eax 00000005  ebx f643c9f0  ecx 719e6c50  edx 00000000
    edi 00000000  esi f73da150
    ebp ffaaccd8  esp ffaaccc0  eip f64155ba

backtrace:
      #00 pc 0004c5ba  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::LoadedIdmap::IsUpToDate() const+26) (BuildId: 5da811609d8437e97d866d83f6ab6c18)
      #01 pc 0002eac1  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ApkAssets::IsUpToDate() const+49) (BuildId: 5da811609d8437e97d866d83f6ab6c18)
      #02 pc 001604d0  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeIsUpToDate(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long)+32) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
      #03 pc 00202ee2  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+162) (BuildId: cd049c9ca9f46317ecd7d512d6b856181c4d6d60)
      #04 pc 0204793f  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (offset 0x2000000) (android.content.res.ApkAssets.isUpToDate+63)
      #05 pc 0206ce04  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (offset 0x2000000) (android.content.res.AssetManager.isUpToDate+132)
```

This is my Git repo. https://github.com/MarkusNowotny/WorkerTest
There you will find the source code which will cause the crash. I have two branches. One will run successfully and the other will cause the crash. You can see the difference between those two branches here: https://github.com/MarkusNowotny/WorkerTest/compare/failure

I'm starting the WorkContinuation from an activity with the activity context for WorkManager initialisation.

Unfortunately, after hours of searching, I got no result. Hopefully you can help me with my project.

This error does not occur often, maybe 1 time out of 20 attempts, so you have to run the code several times.

I'm using:

- Android Studio 4.2 Canary 13
- Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.0-alpha13
- Kotlin 1.4.10
- Windows 10
- Emulator: Pixel C API 30 Android 11 (Google API version)